# Strange variable assignment

Tags: php, language-features

I have a code:

```
<?php
echo $var=@E��Sᴦt��Pט㘦�j옦^'"ɘҘ=�^X��5';
?>
```

It will output 'gzinflate'. How did it happen?
I think this is some feature of php when working with strings, but what?

Code in correct encoding (ASCII), but have a lot of special symbols.
If the code is broken, try download txt file http://content.wuala.com/contents/dador/web/code.txt with it.

Comment: That outputs: `g&'ow�R�\���PRP�`  http://codepad.org/SYmQE7l2

Comment: And code from link: http://codepad.org/sGF68OCJ outputs: `g:)n!!��SrV�o�`

Comment: Them characters are not ASCII there more like utf=8/16/32 `Ҙ`= http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabet `U+0400–U+04FF`

Comment: @Neal: try to download the code (don't copy/paste), works here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

> echo $var=@E³»Sát ôP×˜ã…jì^'"ÉÒ=‡ ñ€5';

boils down to

```
echo             // ...
$var             // ...
=                // ...
@                // error supressor
E³»Sát ôP×˜ã…jì  // an undefined constant, treated as a string
^                //  xor
'"ÉÒ=‡ ñ€5'      // another string literal
```

and the resulting string is just `gzinflate`

Comment: Indeed, just a bit of harmless bit-fun (or the start of some obscured malicious code, seems like something crackers would do to prevent easy grepping on injected code).

Comment: Thanks you. Who wants to learn more about xor and others, may go to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php